# Successively listing the different results, definitions

Tags: lists

[image]

How I can enumerate of this way?
In a chapter 13,
Definition 13.1
Definition 13.2
Definition 13.3
Proposition 13.4

That is, that the number of the proposition is the successor of the last result or definition etc.

Comment: What package are you using to define your definitions, propositions, theorems, lemmas, examples, ...?

Answer (score 1):

Note: *It would be better if provide MWE with your question*.

All you need to set a hierarchy according to your need. The following two lines of code may help you.

```
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[definition]{Proposition}
```

**Explanation:**

`\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]`

This is the example where parameter `[section]` denotes that restarts the *definition counter* at every new section.

`\newtheorem{proposition}[definition]{Proposition}`

In this case, a `proposition` is created, it will use the same counter as the `definition` environment.

For better understanding:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[definition]{Proposition}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
Theorems can easily be defined:

\setcounter{section}{13}

\begin{definition}
Text A
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}
Text B
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}
Text C
\end{definition}

\begin{proposition}
Text D
\end{proposition}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks. But a doubt.
If i wanted to have
Definition 1
Proposition 2
Theorem 3
Proposition 4
Will I have to do two new proposition theorem?

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[definition]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{theorem}[proposition]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}?

Comment: No, this is not the right way. First design a hierarchy: which follows what? Then define `\newtheorem` accordingly.

Comment: Actually,  I would like  that each "new theorem" is listed one after another. An example of this is Wong's an introduction to the pseudo differential operators book. Is something like that possible?